# Importing QuaggaJS into Angular 2 project

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, quaggajs

I'm trying to use QuaggaJS in Angular 2. The project uses routes so when the add page is clicked on, QuaggaJS should load the Javascript files as below:

```
<script src="vendor/jquery-1.9.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../dist/quagga.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="live_w_locator.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However, these don't load. There is a provided quagga.d.ts file that allows use of the QuaggaJS API, but I'm not sure how to use it.

Do the Javascript files need to be imported into the project as it is for typescript components?

Component file:

```
ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this);
    let state = {
      inputStream: {
        type : "LiveStream",
        constraints: {
          width: {min: 640},
          height: {min: 480},
          facingMode: "environment",
          aspectRatio: {min: 1, max: 2}
        }
      },
      locator: {
        patchSize: "medium",
        halfSample: true
      },
      numOfWorkers: 4,
      decoder: {
        readers : [{
          format: "code_128_reader",
          config: {}
        }]
      },
      locate: true
    };

    Quagga.init(state, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
      }

      Quagga.start();
    });

    Quagga.onProcessed(this.onProcessed);

    Quagga.onDetected(this.logCode);

  }

  onProcessed(result: any) {
    var drawingCtx = Quagga.canvas.ctx.overlay,
    drawingCanvas = Quagga.canvas.dom.overlay;

    if (result) {
      if (result.boxes) {
        drawingCtx.clearRect(0, 0, parseInt(drawingCanvas.getAttribute("width")), parseInt(drawingCanvas.getAttribute("height")));
        result.boxes.filter(function (box) {
          return box !== result.box;
        }).forEach(function (box) {
          Quagga.ImageDebug.drawPath(box, {x: 0, y: 1}, drawingCtx, {color: "green", lineWidth: 2});
        });
      }

      if (result.box) {
        Quagga.ImageDebug.drawPath(result.box, {x: 0, y: 1}, drawingCtx, {color: "#00F", lineWidth: 2});
      }

      if (result.codeResult && result.codeResult.code) {
        Quagga.ImageDebug.drawPath(result.line, {x: 'x', y: 'y'}, drawingCtx, {color: 'red', lineWidth: 3});
      }
    }
  }

  logCode(result) {
    this.lastResult = result.codeResult.code;
    console.log(this);
  }
```

Comment: Install it using npm, see https://github.com/serratus/quaggaJS#installing

Comment: I've managed to install Quagga through npm in its directory but still having trouble in importing it into the project: import Quagga from 'quagga';

Comment: Having trouble how?

Comment: I've imported Quagga into the app.module as above but struggling with calling the API or using the javascript? I have the following in the component file: